# How to set umask for php-fpm in Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, php-fpm, umask, systemd

I cannot find where to set umask (to set proper permissions to files created by php scripts) 
in Fedora 19. (specifically, I want new files to have the permissions 664)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how I finally did it, in case this helps someone:

Create the file

```
/etc/systemd/system/php5-fpm.service.d/php5-fpm.service.conf
```

(it must end in `.conf`) with the content:

```
.include /lib/systemd/system/php5-fpm.service

[Service]
UMask=0002
```

Then run

```
 systemctl daemon-reload
 systemctl restart php5-fpm
```

Comment: You probably [don't need](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Editing_provided_unit_files) `include`: `To edit a unit file provided by a package, you can create a directory called /etc/systemd/system/unit.d/ for example /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/ and place *.conf files in there to override or add new options. systemd will parse these *.conf files and apply them on top of the original unit.` And the name of the file may be different. It works for me on `Arch Linux`.

Answer (score 11):

Just run:
`systemctl edit unit.service`. This will create override.conf for service. Inside add:
`[Service]
UMask=0002`

And reenable service: `systemctl reenable unit.service`
In your case unit.service is httpd.service

Comment: this is the simplest and future proof way, works debian 11

Answer (score 0):

if you have a systemd service on CentOs7 
you need to stop the service and enable it again to have it fixed

```
systemctl stop httpd
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
```

Add this:

```
[Service]
UMask=0002
```

Save the file with esc ZZ.  Enable and start apache again:

```
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd
```

Then the funny part is that i have chmod 774 and not 770
mmm

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache apache  405163 Apr 26 11:04 0FreeRADIUS.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache apache   42496 Apr 26 11:05 admiraliteitsraad.doc
```

Comment: Never edit the unit files in /usr/lib.  Package updates can blow them away.  Instead, edit them in /etc/systemd/system instead.